# Hooking a function from an injected DLL into an existing method at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, cil, monkeypatching, dll-injection

First off, i am not trying to hack any game. I want to be able to create mods for games written in C# without mod support.

Lets assume the game contains this simple class:

```
namespace Game
{
    public class GameLogic
    {
        public void DoThis() {
            Console.WriteLine("Game-Logic");
        }
    }
}
```

The `DoThis()` method is called every second.
Now i want the following `ExtraLogic()` method to be hooked to the start or end of the function.

```
namespace GamePatch
{
    public class Mod
    {
        public void ExtraLogic() {
            Console.WriteLine("Extra-Logic");
        }
    }
}
```

Of course i have to inject the mod-dll with my custom code first.
Lets say i already have a bootstrapper to inject the dll and call a `DllMain` method.
Since i can't easily monkey patch the logic into the method in c#, i probably have to somehow modify instructions in memory.

Is it possible to somehow insert a call to the `ExtraLogic()`?
I know it is possible to somehow modify the IL code at runtime.
And what would i have to do if the `DoThis()` method had parameters that i wanted to use in my mod logic?

I'd prefer a solution without frameworks, since i want to understand the process of getting my method to execute.

Comment: I don't have any experience with this, but a search gave me a startpoint where I would start: [MethodRental.SwapMethodBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.methodrental.swapmethodbody?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: maybe this lib works for you: https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, that link seems to suggest that you can only swap the body of a method in a dynamic module. But even if it can be used more generally, types/methods/fields referenced in the IL are referenced via metadata tokens which are module specific; its very unlikely the game modules will have existing references the methods to be injected, so I don't think you can use this to add the calls anyway.